# Javascript easyautocomplete TypeError

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to run http://easyautocomplete.com/example/select-event
But whenever I fill inputOne it returns error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).getSelectedItemIndex is not a function
    at Object.onSelectItemEvent (data.js:6)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js:10)
getSelectedItemData()    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)
    at Function.each (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.each (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
    at m.fn.init.trigger (jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3)
    at j (jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js:10)
```

Code (html):

```
<script src="http://easyautocomplete.com/javascripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://easyautocomplete.com/dist/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://easyautocomplete.com/dist/easy-autocomplete.min.css">

<input id="inputOne" placeholder="X-men character" />
<input id="inputTwo" placeholder="Real name" />

<script>
var options = {

    data: [
        {"character": "Cyclops", "realName": "Scott Summers"},
        {"character": "Professor X", "realName": "Charles Francis Xavier"},
        {"character": "Mystique", "realName": "Raven Darkholme"},
        {"character": "Magneto", "realName": "Max Eisenhardt"},
        {"character": "Storm", "realName": "Ororo Monroe"},
        {"character": "Wolverine", "realName": "James Howlett"}
    ],

    getValue: function(element) {
        return element.character;
    },

    list: {
        onSelectItemEvent: function() {
            var selectedItemValue = $("#inputOne").getSelectedItemData().realName;

            $("#inputTwo").val(selectedItemValue).trigger("change");
        },
        onHideListEvent: function() {
            $("#inputTwo").val("").trigger("change");
        }
    }
};

$("#inputOne").easyAutocomplete(options);
</script>
```

I'm running python flask to serve the files. Let me know what you think.

Comment: `Code` can be placed directly into questions (and should be). Use the `Code Sample` option in the toolbar.

Comment: The problem could be with the browser. It is working fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: I'm runnng this code in python-flask which might be the issue.

Comment: Ah found it, jquery was linked twice :/